# How can i create a hamburger menu with Sub Menu inside

Tags: ios, swift, hamburger-menu

I am working on an app in which requirement is to create a hamburger menu with submenu in it like[image: like this]

I tried different method using table inside table view cell etc but unable to create this menu.
if someone has a solution then recommend me

Comment: Try to use expandable cells using tableview

Comment: You can use a mix of Autolayout, constraint heights and animations to achieve that. Expand on tap, collapse on tap again by changing height with animation

Comment: I know this is a technical question but keep in mind that Hamburger Menus aren't a standard navigation concept in iOS and that other navigation concepts are far more common and recommended. See for example: [Is it OK to use hamburger menus in iOS?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/86941/is-it-ok-to-use-hamburger-menus-in-ios)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create such an item structure as your data source

```
struct Item {
    let text: String
    var subItems: [String]?
    var isExpanded = false
    init(_ text: String, items: [String]? = nil) {
        self.text = text
        self.subItems = items
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    private let imgOpen = UIImage(named: "open")
    private let imgClose = UIImage(named: "close")

    private var dataSource = [Item]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "groupCell")
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        self.dataSource.append(Item("HOME"))
        self.dataSource.append(Item("ABOUT US"))
        self.dataSource.append(Item("OUR PROJECTS", items: ["Project-1", "Project-2", "..."]))
        self.dataSource.append(Item("BAHRIA TOWN PHASE 1 - 7"))
        self.dataSource.append(Item("BAHRIA TOWN PHASE 8"))
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.dataSource.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let item = self.dataSource[section]
        if item.isExpanded, let count = item.subItems?.count {
            return count + 1
        }

        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let item = self.dataSource[indexPath.section]

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell", for: indexPath)
            var imageView: UIImageView?
            if indexPath.row > 0, let text = item.subItems?[indexPath.row - 1] {
                cell.textLabel?.text = text
            } else {
                cell.textLabel?.text = item.text
                if item.subItems != nil {
                    imageView = UIImageView(image: item.isExpanded ? self.imgClose : self.imgOpen)
                }
            }
            cell.accessoryView = imageView

            return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item = self.dataSource[indexPath.section]
        if indexPath.row == 0 && item.subItems != nil {
            self.dataSource[indexPath.section].isExpanded = !item.isExpanded
            let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(indexSet, with: .automatic)
        } else {
            // non-expandable menu item tapped
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Awesome approach.  Love it.

Comment: can i get name of item if it is non expandable?

Comment: Use `dataSource` with an index, like so `dataSource[index].text`, if you need name of sub item use `dataSource[index].subItems?[subRowIndex]`

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the process.

- First, create the hamburger menu: for this, I recommend using this 3rd party library: https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController
  With the help of this, it is very easy to create a side out menu from the left side of the screen.
  The best thing that you will get a ViewController which will responsible for the menu, so you can easily customize it.
- Second, as mentioned below, you should use a tableView with expandable cells. The best way to do this is to basically just show the headers of the cells. If the user taps on a header, then show the actual cell. (rowheight > 0). There is a tutorial about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSKUYRsMCrM

Answer (score 0):

-> you can create a sliding drawer menu(hamburger menu) using any of the following libraries:

```
1) REFrostedViewController
2) SWRevealViewController or any other
```

-> Sub Menu: In the drawer view controller, you have to add a table view and implement expandable/collapsible sections to display a submenu. You can follow any tutorial explaining about expand-collapse table view sections. Some of the tutorial links are below:

```
https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section
https://medium.com/@legonaftik/uitableview-with-collapsible-sections-927d726b985c
```

Answer (score 0):

1st Follow `https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu`.

**And then to make EXPANDABLE Cells**:-

You just need to create 2 Cells in `UITableView`(In Storyboard). First cell for those who are not expandable and Second cell for the expandable.

```
class SideMenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK:- Constants And Vars
    var isOurProjectCellExpanded = false
}

class SideMenuTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "simpleCell", for: indexPath) as! SideMenuBasicTableViewCell
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                cell.itemName.text = "HOME"
                break
            case 1:
                cell.itemName.text = "About Us"
                break
            case 2:
                if(isOurProjectCellExpanded){
                    //expandedCell
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expandedCell", for: indexPath) as! SideMenuBasicTableViewCell
                    cell.itemName.text = "Our Projects"
                    return cell
                }else{
                    cell.arrowDownImageView.isHidden = false
                    cell.itemName.text = "Our Projects"
                }
                break
            case 3:
                cell.itemName.text = "Bahria Town phase 1-7"
                break
            case 4:
                cell.itemName.text = "Bahria Town phase 8"
                break
            default:
                break
            }
            return cell
        }

     //And in `DidSelectRow` Method
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if(indexPath.row == 2){
                if(isOurProjectCellExpanded){
                    isOurProjectCellExpanded = false
                    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
                }else{
                    isOurProjectCellExpanded = true
                    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
                }
            }else if(indexPath.row == 0){
                // Handle it yourself
            }else if(indexPath.row == 1){
                // Handle it yourself
            }else if(indexPath.row == 3){
                // Handle it yourself
            }else if(indexPath.row == 4){
                // Handle it yourself
            }
        }

    }
```