# table view inside table view in swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dropdown

I tried tableview inside tableview, sub tableview contains drop down of 4 fields and if click on sub table view row then it will hide and shown in the dropdown button. pls check my below code.

```
import UIKit

var empname = ["Alex","Henry","Smith","Carey","Stephen"]
var insideArr = ["Retired", "Newly Joined", "Resigned", "Closed" ]

class EmpViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView.tag == 100{
        return empname.count
        }
        else{
            return insideArr.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                if tableView.tag == 100{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! DataCell
        cell.emp.text = empname[indexPath.item] as? String
 cell.btndropdown.tag = indexPath.row
 cell.btndropdown.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btndrop(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
 cell.btndropdown.setTitle("Open", for: .normal)
        return cell
        }
  else{
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InnerDataCell", for: indexPath) as! InnerDataCell
        cell.role.text = insideArr[indexPath.item] as? String
         return cell
        }
    }

       @objc func btndrop(sender: UIButton!){
        if(sender.isSelected == true){
                       sender.isSelected = false
        }
        else{
            sender.isSelected = true

        }
    }

}



class InnerDataCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblInsideName: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}


class DataCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var tblInsideTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sitename: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btndropdown: UIButton!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}

extension DataCell{
  func setTableViewDataSourceDelegate
    <D:UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource>
    (_ dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int){
      tblInsideTableView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
      tblInsideTableView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
      tblInsideTableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

[image]

Required output:

Emp1      select V

Emp2      select V

if click on Select button in 1st index, then

Emp1      Select V

Emp2      Select V
          Retired
          Newly Joined
          Resigned
          Closed

if click on closed option then it will be

Emp1      Select V

Emp2      Closed V

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/ . Check this out for using expandable table view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55848698/6737277 this one might help you

Comment: you can achieve this by One UITableview with 2 sections.